# Unable to successfully set up SNS on CodeBuild project through CFT but works manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I'm trying to get an SNS system set up to send out an email whenever a build fails. At the moment I just have it set to send a notification when it reaches several different stages for testing purposes.

I've followed the tutorial from AWS so many times that I've memorized the entire process but something isn't working when I translate that into a CFT.

I receive the confirmation email when everything is created but afterwards when I click on the "Start Build" button in my CodeBuild project I don't receive any further emails about the build status.
If I do this manually though I will receive all the expected emails.

**sns-build-notifications.yml**

```yaml
###
### Stack Name: sns-build-notifications
###
### Template Name: sns-build-notifications.yml
###
### Description: Creates a notification system that emails users when a
###              specified build fails
###

AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'

Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  rSnsTopicDemo:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: rSnsTopicDemo
      Subscription:
        - Protocol: email
          Endpoint: myEmail@gmail.com

  rCloudWatchEventRuleDemo:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Delete when finished
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.codebuild
        detail-type:
          - CodeBuild Build State Change
        detail:
          build-status:
            - IN_PROGRESS
            - SUCCEEDED
            - FAILED
            - STOPPED
          project-name:
            - CodeBuildStateChangeDemo
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Ref rSnsTopicDemo
          Id: CodeBuildStateChangeDemo
          InputTransformer:
              InputPathsMap:
                build-status: "$.detail.build-status"
              InputTemplate: |
                "Build has entered status: '<build-status>'"
```

I'm attaching some images of my resources created through the CFT.
Some of the names might differ from what I've described here just for security purposes.

**CodeBuildStateChangeDemo**
[image]

**rSnsTopicDemo**
[image]

**rSnsTopicDemo Subscription**
[image]

**CloudWatch Event Rule**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you posted, I see that **there is no** [AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-policy.html) allowing CW events to submit any message to it.

The topic policy would need to be **explicitly created in CFN**. Console does this in the background. Example policy is as follows:

```
{
  "Sid": "AWSEvents_kkk_Id983908485049",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sns:Publish",
  "Resource": "<my-sns-topic-arn>"
}
```

Comment: Alright I'll go ahead and try this, thanks for the suggestion. One thing I did notice though is that if I split the two resources above into two separate CFT's and ran them at different times (first the Topic/Sub and then the CW Event) everything works just fine. Does this knowledge change your answer? This is without the TopicPolicy you've suggested.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Interesting. I'm not sure how that would work. You can check sns policy in console. You can compare what is the policy when you setup manually everything through console, and what's different where it is done through one or two CFTs.

Comment: I was missing the TopicPolicy resource just as you said. Thanks for the help. A note to others, the JSON in this answer is actually the `Properties` portion of the TopicPolicy. You still need to include the rest of the resource which is shown in the link Marcin shared.